# PrettyFaces 2.0.12.Final + JSF 2.2 + PrimeFaces 5.2.RC3 + Spring Securities

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, spring-security, prettyfaces

- how can implement PrettyFaces for URL rewriting & hiding in existing application (JSF 2.2, PrimeFaces 5.2 RC3 & Spring Securities)
- My Code : preety-config.xml

  ```
  <pretty-config xmlns="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces
                    http://ocpsoft.org/xml/ns/prettyfaces/rewrite-config-prettyfaces.xsd">
  ```
- My complete pom.xml

  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
     4.0.0

  com.invessence
        parent
        1.0-SNAPSHOT
        ../parent/pom.xml

  web
     1.0-SNAPSHOT
     war

  install
        
           
           
              org.apache.maven.plugins
              maven-resources-plugin
              2.3
              
                 
                 UTF-8
              
           
           
           
              org.apache.maven.plugins
              maven-war-plugin
              2.1.1
              
                 
                    
                       true
                       src/main/webapp
                       
                          **/*.html***
                          /.xhtml
                          **/*.xml
                          
                       
                    
                 
              
           
        
        
           
              src/main/resources
              true

  com.invessence
           core
           ${invessence.version}

  ```
      <dependency>
       <groupId>com.invessence</groupId>
       <artifactId>broker-webservices</artifactId>
       <version>${invessence.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.invessence</groupId>
       <artifactId>emailer</artifactId>
       <version>${invessence.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.invessence</groupId>
       <artifactId>invmodel</artifactId>
       <version>${invessence.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>webcab</groupId>
        <artifactId>portfolioJ2SE</artifactId>
     </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.invessence</groupId>
          <artifactId>yodlee-services</artifactId>
          <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
       <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
       <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
       <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.code.maven-play-plugin.org.playframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>jj-simplecaptcha</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-struts</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-aspects</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-openid</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-remoting</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
       <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>avalon-framework</groupId>
         <artifactId>avalon-framework</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.avalon.logkit</groupId>
         <artifactId>avalon-logkit</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
          <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
          <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
          <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      </dependency>

    <!-- Primefaces dependecies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
     </dependency>

    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
          <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
          <version>5.2.RC3</version>
      </dependency>
       <dependency>
         <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
         <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
         <version>1.2.1</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.6</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.1</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
          <version>1.2</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

    <!-- Other Primefaces extensions dependencies -->
    <!-- OCPSoft Preetyfaces -->
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
          <artifactId>rewrite-servlet</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
        <artifactId>rewrite-config-prettyfaces</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- itext and other for exporting documents in pdf/excel format -->

    <dependency>
          <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
          <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
          <version>5.1.3</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
           <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
           <version>2.1.7</version>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                   <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                   <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                   <artifactId>bctsp-jdk14</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>
  ```

Comment: - is any additional configuration required?

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually add rules to your pretty-config.xml file. PrettyFaces won't do anything unless you tell it to. Though, for applying rewriting to an existing app, I'd suggest looking at http://ocpsoft.com/rewrite. It's a lot more powerful for doing broad, application-wide rewriting.

Comment: Thank Lincoln, finally tuckey implemented in my application.

Comment: Glad I could help, what was your solution?